# Angular 8, rendering a table-based component without enclosing tags

Tags: angular, angular-components

Here is what I am trying to accomplish. I have a **table** element on my HTML page. The table has a complicated row structure. Every three rows are related to a single data item. Right now, the table is hard-coded HTML and very complex/messy looking, so I'd like to make a component instead, which will replace many **tr** elements and also allow me to use *ngIf a little more cleanly.

So, just to be clear, instead of this (the existing HTML, I removed all the **td**, **tbody** and other tags for simplicity sake):

```
<table>
  <tr>Item1</tr>
  <tr>Item1</tr>
  <tr>Item1</tr>
  <tr>Item2</tr>
  <tr>Item2</tr>
  <tr>Item2</tr>
  <tr>Item3</tr>
  <tr>Item3</tr>
  <tr>Item3</tr>
</table>
```

I want to use this:

```
<table>
  <app-row item="item1"></app-row>
  <app-row item="item2"></app-row>
  <app-row item="item3"></app-row>
</table>
```

or something like this:

```
<table>
  <app-row *ngFor="let item of items"></app-row>
</table>
```

SO HERE IS THE PROBLEM

When I try to do this using a component, what I end up with is this. It has the component tag wrapped around each section of **tr** elements. This is not only improper HTML, but it breaks CSS selectors which expect a table to look like **table>tr>td**.

```
<table>
  <app-row>
    <tr>Item1</tr>
    <tr>Item1</tr>
    <tr>Item1</tr>
  </app-row>
  <app-row>
    <tr>Item2</tr>
    <tr>Item2</tr>
    <tr>Item2</tr>
  </app-row>
  <app-row>
    <tr>Item3</tr>
    <tr>Item3</tr>
    <tr>Item3</tr>
  </app-row>
</table>
```

I did a little research and everyone seems to recommend using an "attribute selector" instead, which might look like this:

```
<table>
  <tr appRow item="item1"></tr>
  <tr appRow item="item2"></tr>
  <tr appRow item="item3"></tr>
</table>
```

However that results in having double tr tags in all cases.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <tr>Item1</tr>
        <tr>Item1</tr>
        <tr>Item1</tr>
    </tr>
      <tr>
        <tr>Item2</tr>
        <tr>Item2</tr>
        <tr>Item2</tr>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <tr>Item3</tr>
        <tr>Item3</tr>
        <tr>Item3</tr>
      </tr>
</table>
```

Can anyone recommend a way to create this structure so that I have the correct resulting HTML without additional tags?

Comment: The only thing that comes to my mind are templates. Check out [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gnkrdx) example I created, maybe it can give you some ideas...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using the **attribute selector** is also a solution , but you have to apply the attribute to the `<table>` and leave you component generate the `<tr>`s.

```
<table appRow *ngFor="let item of items" [itemInput]="item">
</table>
```